# Many to Many vs. One to Many in MongoDB design with MongoMapper

Tags: database-design, mongodb, many-to-many, one-to-many, mongomapper

There is one example like this:

```
class Book
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :title
  key :author_ids, Array
  many :authors, :in => :author_ids
end

class Author
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name
end
```

Is it equivalent to

```
class Book
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :title
  many :AuthorHasBook
end

class AuthorHasBook
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :written_time

  belongs_to :book, :class_name => "Book"
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "Author"
end

class Author
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name
  many :AuthorHasBook
end
```

Which is better? I guess if I need to add some fields for the "relational" entity, I have to use the 2nd solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use

```
many :author_has_books
```

so MongoMapper can pick up your class name and associate it. Not sure it will work otherwise.

The only other difference is that you can have reverse many to many associations.